# Unable to make a retry for API call Getting the success event

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables, rxjs-pipeable-operators

I am having a requirement to make multiple API calls using fork-join we need to make a retry if any one of the API calls after 3seconds and even then the API is failing then we should not go to subscribe. And the retry should also happen for one time retry that's all
For the above requirement, I implemented in the below way:-

```
const getPosts = this.api
      .get("/posts/")
      .pipe(catchError(this.getCatchError));
    const getPostsFaliure = this.api.get("/postsasdfs/")
      .pipe(catchError(this.getCatchError));
    ;
    forkJoin(getPosts, getPostsFaliure)
      .pipe(
        retryWhen(err => {
          err.pipe(
            tap(val => console.log(`Value ${val} was too high!`)),
            //restart in 6 seconds
            delayWhen(val => timer(val * 1000))
          );
        })
      )
      .subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```

and getCatcherror is there in this way:-

```
getCatchError(error) {
    return of(false);
  }
```

for the above implementation, I am getting the below result:-

```
[Array(100),false]
```

it's not going into err and retry is also not working for me API call is going only one time and  I need to restrict it going to subscribe until the APIs are passing if at least one is failing I need to go to err part of subscribing. And I am having a strict rule to use retry when from rxjs
How to solve this issue

Stackblitz URL:-https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-api-call-cpr1hk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: you should use catchError inside the pipe to catch it and then do you retry logic

Comment: So you are telling me to use this.getCatchError after retrywhen

Comment: ```
    forkJoin(getPosts, getPostsFaliure)
      .pipe(
        retryWhen(errors =>
          errors.pipe(
            delay(3000),
            take(3)
          )
        ),
        catchError(this.getCatchError)
      )
      .subscribe(
        res => {
          console.log("coming into res");
        },
        err => {
          console.log("coming error");
        },
        () => {
          console.log("coming to done");
        }
      );
  
```
I tried in this way but still the retry is happening but not going to error

Comment: You say 3 seconds in the question, but have a delay of 6 seconds somehow in the code. Which is the correct requirement? And how many times do you wish to retry in case of an error?

Comment: Take a look at it: https://indepth.dev/posts/1260/power-of-rxjs-when-using-exponential-backoff

Comment: Ya the time is i can for 3 seconds and the retry should happen 3 times after the failure
ive updated in the stackblitz
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-api-call-cpr1hk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're switching the error to valid notifications with the `of(false)`. It must be removed for the `retryWhen` to be invoked.

1. You could use an explicit variable to denote the retry attempt.
2. Return either `throwError` (to forward the error) or `EMPTY` constant (to complete the observable) from the `catchError` block.

```js
import { forkJoin, throwError, EMPTY } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, retryWhen } from 'rxjs/operators';

const getPosts = this.api.get("/posts/");
const getPostsFaliure = this.api.get("/postsasdfs/");
let retry = 0; // max 3 allowed

forkJoin(getPosts, getPostsFaliure).pipe(
  catchError(err => {
    if (retry <= 3) {
      retry++;
      return throwError(err);
    }
    return EMPTY; // <-- complete the observable if max retries reached
  }),
  retryWhen(err => err.pipe(delay(3000)))
).subscribe(res => console.log(res));
```